# Android Studio GeoDataClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, api, gps, location, geo

I haven't seen this problem anywhere on the internet, also it doesn't seem the library is deprecated, but I just can't add the import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
```

My Android SDK is up to date.

Does anyone know how to use it? Or rather, another way to get my current location on GPS?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0'
```

and

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

because GeoDataClient was added in 11.2.0
you can check this official [document](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/googleapi-migration)

Comment: For newer version of gradle, higher than 4.1. You can use my answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371963/3940133

Answer (score 6):

Try to add

```gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'
```

```
in `build.gradle`, then you may need add

```gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

}

```

finally, ***Build -> rebuild project***.

Comment: aren't you just importing all google play services api at once? It will make your project big and reach 65k method limit easily

Comment: I mean that we just need `play-services-places`, so it will be safe to remove `play-services-maps`,  `play-services` and `play-services-location`

Comment: I am aware this answer have some problem, but I can remember which `jar` contains `com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;`, so I suggest you to delete other `jar`  .

Answer (score 1):

Adding  just this one dependency to `apps` **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

and below code to `project's` **build.gradle** should work.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this link can help you.It's about using Geo location in android app
https://www.toptal.com/android/android-developers-guide-to-google-location-services-api

Answer (score 0):

@Xianwei's answer is working, but it is good to always improve our code over time, since there will always a new, better and simpler implementation. Basically it is more detail and improvement from @Xianwei's answer.

Add `google()` repository in your **top-level** `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Add **places google play service** dependency in your **app-level** `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Your other dependencies...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:x.x.x'
}
```

Where **x.x.x** is the newest version of `play-services-places`, current working version is **15.0.1**.
You can check the newest version in the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency in `build.gradle`

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'`